# Control modified keys show up as wrong keys

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, nixos

I'm using WSL 1.0 Ubuntu inside Windows Terminal v1.11.2921.0 from a Windows machine, to SSH into a NixOS box (Linux)

On Windows, I am using the Programmer Dvorak keyboard layout. I also remapped `Caps Lock` -> `Ctrl`, and swapped locations of `$` and `@` keys using PowerToys. (When shift is held, `$` becomes `~` and `@` becomes `^`)

On NixOS, it is using the default US keyboard layout:

```
$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc104
     X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

The programmer dvorak keys generally work correctly through SSH however, even though the NixOS box is using US keyboard layout.

Now for the problem... On my keyboard layout, the `]` key is where the `0` key normally is in QWERTY. It is `]` when you press it normally, and `6` when you press it with shift. When I try to use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+]`, it gets interpreted as `Ctrl+^` instead.

Here is `showkey -a` output on both NixOS SSH session, AND just in the regular WSL Ubuntu terminal. (Same issue in both, which makes me think this is a Windows problem...)

The first line is me pressing the `]` key, and the second line is me holding Control and pressing `]` key.

```
$ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

]        93 0135 0x5d
^^       30 0036 0x1e
```

I noticed several other of my keys are not interpreted how I would expect when I use `Ctrl` modifier with them. Does anyone know what might explain this behavior, and how to fix or work around it?

And, a quick debugging question- I would also like to see if this problem occurs on Windows itself (like not inside WSL Ubuntu or Windows Terminal), to help isolate it further, but couldn't figure out how. Is there some equivalent of `showkey -a` on Windows I can use to see if the problem is happening outside of Windows Terminal / Linux sessions?

Comment: You might want to test the keymap (and variant+model+options) by using setxkbmap.
I am not quite sure why localectl was not working as expected, but with setxkbmap it is working for me. I had strange mapping behaviors as well.

Comment: Update- This is due to a bug in Windows Terminal. https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/13319